# Why does `grunt watch` fail with "ENOENT, no such file or directory" although file exists

Tags: node.js, build, gruntjs

When I run `grunt watch`, `watch` works once:  Grunt compiles/minifies all files, after I've  edited and saved a Javascript file. But when I edit and save that same file *again*, Grunt says `ENOENT, no such file or directory 'client/debiki/debiki-action-edit.js'`.

(The file mentioned is the file I just modified.) However the file does exist:

```
$ ll client/debiki/debiki-action-edit.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kajmagnus kajmagnus 22497 Jan 21 23:47 client/debiki/debiki-action-edit.js
```

And if I run `grunt` directly from the command line (without `watch`) Grunt is always able to compile everything without any error.

What's happening? How can I make `grunt watch` work?

**Details:**

Ubuntu Linux, Grunt v0.3.17, Node.js v0.8.4. I use the built-in `watch` task, not `grunt-contrib-watch`.

The complete Grunt error message

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:75
      throw grunt.task.taskError(e.message, e);
                       ^
TaskError: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'client/debiki/debiki-action-edit.js'
    at Task.taskError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:59:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:75:24
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.expandByType (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:69:40)
    at Timer.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/tasks/watch.js:158:44)
    at Timer.exports.setInterval.timer.ontimeout (timers.js:234:14)
```

Comment: It may be worth installing the latest 0.4.0 release candidate and using grunt-contrib-watch (as well as any other updated tasks). Many fixes and features have been added to 0.4.0-compatible tasks and internal 0.3.x tasks have all been moved out and are supported as part of grunt-contrib-*.

Comment: @jsoverson Upgrading to Grunt 0.4.x seems to have solved the issue — now `grunt watch` doesn't die.

Comment: @jsoverson If you'd like to convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it and close this question. (Otherwise I'll add an answer myself after some week and accept and close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth installing the latest 0.4.0 release candidate and using grunt-contrib-watch (as well as any other updated tasks). Many fixes and features have been added to 0.4.0-compatible tasks and internal 0.3.x tasks have all been moved out and are supported as part of grunt-contrib-*

*Converted comment to an answer for the sake of being approved and closing this question*